# "cannot find declaration to go to" when importing java project

Tags: java, android-studio

I imported a non-android Java project from github using `File > New > Project From Version Control > Github`. This is a very basic project. The package and class structure looks as follows:

```
java-json.jar
postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar
src
  com
    mysite
      main
        Main.java
        Report.java
        ...
```

I went to Project Structure > Project SDK, and I selected the jdk8, which I have installed on my machine. At this point, I am able to view the files in the window. However, when I ctrl+click on any method or class, I get the error "cannot find declaration to go to". All these java classes are within the same package, com.mysite.main, as shown above. What may I be doing wrong here?

Comment: What build AS are you using?

Comment: Also, when I go to Run > Edit Configurations > Application > Main Class > Project and select my main class (with main method), the "Ok" button is grayed out. It won't let me select it. The configuration simply says "Error: No Main Class Specified".

Comment: I give up. Im just going to use IntelliJ.